# rounding-up numbers within a tuple

Tags: python

Is there anyway I could round-up numbers within a tuple to two decimal points,
from this:

```
('string 1', 1234.55555, 5.66666, 'string2')
```

to this:

```
('string 1', 1234.56, 5.67, 'string2')
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is related thread on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your tuple has a fixed size of 4 and the position of the floats is always the same, you can do this:

```
>>> t = ('string 1', 1234.55555, 5.66666, 'string2')
>>> t2 = (t[0], round(t[1], 2), round(t[2], 2), t[3])
>>> t2
('string 1', 1234.56, 5.67, 'string2')
```

The general solution would be:

```
>>> t2 = tuple(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, float) and round(x, 2) or x, t))
>>> t2
('string 1', 1234.56, 5.67, 'string2')
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. The link has been provided as comment. It would be better to just point to it and mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: The link wasn't there when I've written my answer, and the questions might be different. Maybe he has troubles to deal with the tuple and not with floating point arithmetic in general?

Comment: @pyfunc I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.  It's related but I think the "general solution" posted by @tux21b is what the OP may be trying to get at.  At least that's how I understand it, how to round floats/doubles in a tuple that contains other values of other types.

Comment: @pyfunc: It's RELATED not DUPLICATE. The OP's problem may well be that `atuple[1] = round(atuple[1], 2)` fails whereas it works with a list. Novel thought: try asking the OP what his real problem is.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension solution:

```
t = ('string 1', 1234.55555, 5.66666, 'string2')
solution = tuple([round(x,2) if isinstance(x, float) else x for x in t])
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid [issues with floating-point rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points), you can use [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) objects:

```
"""
>>> rounded_tuple(('string 1', 1234.55555, 5.66666, 'string2'))
('string 1', Decimal('1234.56'), Decimal('5.67'), 'string2')
"""
from decimal import Decimal
def round_if_float(value):
    if isinstance(value, float):
        return Decimal(str(value)).quantize(Decimal('1.00'))
    else:
        return value

def rounded_tuple(tup):
    return tuple(round_if_float(value) for value in tup)
```

`rounded_tuple` uses a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) inside a call to tuple.